# Shopware 6 linking sites from Shopping Experiences

Tags: shopware

I am looking for a way to dynamically link pages created in Shopping Experiences.
Is it possible to add a link, for example, the Cars website on the Engines website?
Or add a reference to the Engines page on the product page?

Answer (score 0):

Shopware provides the functioanlity to use technical urls that are dynamically changed to the current SEO url. The structure is like that:

Products:

```
<a href="124c71d524604ccbad6042edce3ac799/detail/uuid#"> Link Title </a>
```

Categories:

```
<a href="124c71d524604ccbad6042edce3ac799/navigation/uuid#"> Link Title </a>
```

Example:

```
 <a href="124c71d524604ccbad6042edce3ac799/navigation/19ca405790ff4f07aac8c599d4317868#"> Link Title</a>
```

This links to a category with the uuid: 19ca405790ff4f07aac8c599d4317868

There is a magic placeholder for the domain at the beginning: 124c71d524604ccbad6042edce3ac799

Everything is defined here: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/e20ad19c2de3c3ccc355a0fd4dfafcb5def0bbe9/src/Core/Framework/Seo/SeoUrlPlaceholderHandler.php#L52